# How to detect if the cursor is at a textarea in Firefox

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to map `=` to `next tab` in Firefox except if the cursor is at a text area. Is there a function which detects if the cursor is in a text area?

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
=::Send ^{PgDn}
-::Send ^{PgUp}
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the a_cursor variable and the value i_beam.

Comment: Sometimes even when the value of the `a_cursor` is `ibeam`, the cursor is not in a text area.